# Let $f(x)$ be differentiable at $\mathbb R$, s.t $|f^\prime (x)| \le 6$ . Its given that $f(1)=20$, and $f(9)=68$ , prove that $f(7)=56$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable ate $\mathbb R$, s.t $|f^\prime (x)| \le 6$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$. its given also that $f(1)=20$, and $f(9)=68$ , prove that $f(7)=56$.

I'm thinking about applying  $\text{Mean Value theorem}$ and $\text{Intermediate Value theorem}$, in here but for some reason I miss something and I can't conclude that $f(7)=56$. any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, $f(9) - f(7) = 2f'(c)$ for some $c \in (7,9)$. Since $|f'(c)| \le 6$, $f(9) - f(7) \le 12$, i.e., $f(7) \ge f(9) - 12 = 68 - 12 = 56$. On the other hand, for some $d \in (1,7)$,

$$f(7) = f(1) + 6f'(d) \le f(1) + 36 = 20 + 36 = 56$$

Therefore, $f(7) = 56$.

Comment: Nice! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Is it possible that $f'(x) \neq 6$ for any $x \in (1, 9)$? (EDIT: Just works if you assume $f$ to be continuous).

Comment: According to Mean Value Theorem there is a point $c$ between $1$ and $9$ where $f'(c)=6$, but what are you implying ?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you didn't require $f'$ to be continuous. Otherwise you could have used the fundamental theorem of calculus to see that $f' \equiv 6$. If you assume that there is $y \in (1,9)$ s.t. $f'(y) < 6$ then you could conclude $$48 = f(9) - f(1) = \int_1^9 f'(x) dx < 6 \cdot (9 - 1) = 48$$ (i.e. a contradiction) but the  inequality needs the continuity of $f'$ to extract at least an $\epsilon$-ball around $y$ where $f'(x) < 6$.